# Regex for validation of 9 numbers with single space

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for validating a 9digit number with a single space in-between

So far I have tried

```
^([0-9]{0-9})\s{1}$
```

Comment: So `1 23456789` and `12 3456789` are valid but `1 2 3456789` is not?

Comment: sample input and desired output would be helpful

Comment: Don't use regex. 1) check the length; 2) count the numbers and spaces; 3) check that there are 9 numbers and 1 space.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/VNsfqG/1)

```
^(?=\d+ \d+$)[\d ]{10}$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
1 23456789
12 3456789
123 456789
1234 56789
12345 6789
123456 789
1234567 89
12345678 9

123456789
123456789 
 123456789
1 2 3456789
1 234567890
```

#### Output

Only matches are below.

```
1 23456789
12 3456789
123 456789
1234 56789
12345 6789
123456 789
1234567 89
12345678 9
```

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?=\d+ \d+$)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches the following

  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
  - Match a literal space
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
- `[\d ]{10}` Match any digit or space character exactly 10 times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Wouldn't it also match `1_2_3_45_6`, though?

Comment: @AndyTurner why would that happen? `\d` matches `0-9` not `_`. Maybe you're getting the `\d` and `\w` tokens mixed up?

Comment: Ah, I see, I wasn't noticing the `+` quantifier.

Comment: awesome work @ctwheels, zero length assertions always makes me smile, but isn't the end anchor `$` inside lookahead redundant

Comment: @Aboalnaga not in this case because the lookahead could simply ensure `1 1` matches. It won't ensure no other spaces exist. Try it against `1 2 345678` (two spaces in there)

Comment: oh  that's what happens when escaping tests

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex.

1. Check the length is 10.
2. Count the numbers and spaces:

   ```
   int nSpaces = 0, nNumbers = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
     char c = str.charAt(i);
     if (c == ' ') nSpaces++;
     else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') nNumbers++;
   }
   ```
3. Check that there are 9 numbers and 1 space.

   ```
   if (nSpaces == 1 && nNumbers == 9) { ... }
   ```

Comment: I think he is not concerned with efficiency, but he just wants to either learn or show off to someone :D

Comment: @GCP I didn't say anything about efficiency; I just said don't use regex, with the implication that this way is easier.

Comment: Wouldn't using regex affect performance more compared to using loop and modifying primitives ?

Comment: @GCP yes, it would be more efficient to do it like this, but I didn't say anything about efficiency as a reason to do it like this.

Comment: Why not use regex then ? It saves some space, any reason ?

Comment: @GCP because if you or anybody else reading the code can't remember how the regex works/need to modify it, it is much harder to work it out. You can step through this code with a debugger.

Comment: Oh, so it's about readability. I thought there was another reason or something. Anyhow, thanks for clarification.

Comment: @GCP I provided a [regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995980/3600709) for this question in case the OP decides to go that route or someone else does (maybe someone is using a text editor, for example, and needs to find text with similar requirements as the OP). Regex is a fantastic tool, but it should be used when there aren't *better alternatives* (where things such as performance, manageability, [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), etc. are taken into consideration). It also sometimes just comes down to preference.